# Determining how one date/time range overlaps with the second date/time range?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working out of a `test.csv` file that has 6 columns. I need to open the `csv` and see the over lap between two time ranges.

This is how `csv` looks like:

```
type1 type1_start                    type1_end
a    2019-04-01T00:43:18.046Z    2019-04-01T00:51:35.013Z
b    2019-04-01T02:16:46.490Z    2019-04-01T02:23:23.887Z
c    2019-04-01T03:49:31.981Z    2019-04-01T03:55:16.153Z
d    2019-04-01T05:21:22.131Z    2019-04-01T05:28:05.469Z

type2   type2_start          type2_end
1    2019-04-01T00:35:12.061Z    2019-04-01T00:37:00.783Z
2    2019-04-02T00:37:15.077Z    2019-04-02T00:39:01.393Z
3    2019-04-03T00:39:18.268Z    2019-04-03T00:41:01.844Z
4    2019-04-04T00:41:21.576Z    2019-04-04T00:43:02.071Z
```

I am using a logic that was commented on this earlier. But I can't make the `csv` columns work. I keep getting this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` If I actually enter the date/time to the variables it works!

## working on getting time range intersection correctly

```
colnames = ['type1', 'type1_start', 'type1_end', 'type2', 
'type2_start', 'type2_end']
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=colnames)

A_start = data['type1_start']
A_end = data['type1_end']
B_start= data['type2_start']
B_end = data['type2_end']
type1 = data['type1']
type2 = data['type2']

if A_start < B_end and B_start < A_end:
    print("{} and {} They overlap".format(type1, type2))
else:
    print("{} and {} They do not overlap".format(type1, type2))
```

Would anyone be able to help out?

My csv file is very long, and has six columns. And I have more of type2 rows than type1 rows. I need to check if any of the type2 range falls in the type1 range.

Comment: Did you install [`datetimerange`](https://pypi.org/project/DateTimeRange/)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to import any module for this.  These time stamps can be compared as strings (international format).

Determining if two ranges A and B intersect is a simple condition:

```
  if A.start < B.end and B.start < A.end:  # A and B have an overlap
```

Comment: You are right! I was able to make it work if I inter the times into it, how do I read the columns from `csv`? I keep getting this error when I try calling for the columns. `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with pandas at all.  You may want to ask a separate question for that one.